# WAN IP (or domain name) for OpenVPN client profile

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I've set up OpenVPN on my home server and would now like to connect my phone to it (when using certain networks).

The client site (http://MyServer:943/) displays just fine and I can download the client profile too.

My problem is that when I import that profile into the OpenVPN client app, it shows the VPN server address as `username@server-lan-ip:943`. As I'd like to use it to connect from the outside, this is no good. I fact, I don't want it to display the WAN IP (since that might change), but instead a domain name (I use a DDNS service), eg. `username@server.domain.net:943`.

Is it okay to just manually edit the .opvn file? I looked at it and I saw the address in a couple of places, but I'm worried that a simple "replace all" won't work, because the file also has a lot of hash-looking stuff that might not be valid after an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its OK to edit the .ovpn file - its no more then a text configuration file, and many of us actually create our own programatically.

I'm not sure what hash stuff you are seeing - the line you need to edit is "remote XXXXXX"  where XXXXX is an IP address or domain name.     Of-course, back up your old config file just in case.

FWIW, my config file (which uses certs, not usernames) only has the IP address coded in it in 1 place [ and another VPN has a domain name in its place ]

I wonder if the "hashish looking stuff" you are referring to are actually certificates and public/private keys.   If so, they are not normally bound to an IP address, and can be identified by them being long rows of alphanumeric characters in stanzes starting ----- BEGIN XXXXX------ and ----- END XXXXXXX ------------   (There are probably multiple stanzas)